# Accessing IPB Classes Externally From Main Website

Tags: php, forum, ipb

Hello I have been working with IPB3.4 and I am trying to have some sort of correlation between my main website and forum, specifically users.

I am aware that you can use the IPBMembers class to simply create a new user however I am unsure how I can initialise that class outside of IPB forum base directory.

If anyone has any experience on this topic I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem I had from the above script is after the `init()` method it would redirect me to the forum or cause headers already sent errors so you need to include the below constant for it to work properly outside the IPB forum directories:
`define( 'IPS_ENFORCE_ACCESS', TRUE );`

```
$forumPath = '../forums'; //FORUM FOLDER
define( 'IPS_ENFORCE_ACCESS', TRUE ); // Important so it does not redirect to forums
define( 'IPB_THIS_SCRIPT', 'public' );

require_once( $forumPath.'/initdata.php' );
require_once( IPS_ROOT_PATH . 'sources/base/ipsRegistry.php' );
require_once( IPS_ROOT_PATH . 'sources/base/ipsController.php' );

$ipbRegistry    = ipsRegistry::instance();
$ipbRegistry->init();


$member = IPSMember::load($memberName, 'all', 'username');
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Nathan. I'd been poring through pages and pages of code, looking for just this sort of working example. Many Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

try this from root folder to initialize IPB

```
define('IPB_THIS_SCRIPT', 'public');
require_once( 'initdata.php' );

require_once( IPS_ROOT_PATH . 'sources/base/ipsRegistry.php' );
require_once( IPS_ROOT_PATH . 'sources/base/ipsController.php' );
$ipbRegistry = ipsRegistry::instance();
$ipbRegistry->init();
```

then you can use IPSMember like this

```
$member = IPSMember::load($member_name, 'all', 'username');
```